# 3 part divided website with scrolling animation

Tags: html, css, dynamic, scroll

I want to make a website like that (because I have am really bad in English so I put an image).

```
<html>

<body>

<div id="menu"> </div>
<div id="content1"> </div>
<div id="content2"> </div>
<div id="content3"> </div>

</body>

</html>
```

[image: http://sia1.subirimagenes.net/img/2014/05/18/140518044141849423.png]

I Hope you understand, I know how to fix a div with CSS, but I don't know how to separate my website in different parts and make a scrolling animation.

Hope you all can help me!

Comment: it is lookin like jquery work

Comment: I think you want these 3 websites to be shown in same web page but in scrolling ... means you want to makes 3 boxes in websites and make scrolling option available there. Am i right?

Comment: No, i want a SAME html, divided in 3 parts with a scrolling animation if is posible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand your question, this should be somewhere near what you'd like.

HTML:

```
<div id="menu">
    <h1>This is the menu div</h1>
</div>

<div id="main-container">
    <div id="content-container">
        <div id="content1">
            <h1>This is content 1</h1>
            <a href="#" id="right1">Right</a>
        </div>
        <div id="content2">
            <h1>This is content 2</h1>
            <a href="#" id="left2">Left</a>
            <a href="#" id="right2">Right</a>
        </div>
        <div id="content3">
            <h1>This is content 3</h1>
            <a href="#" id="left3">Left</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

h1 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 25px;
}

#menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
}

#main-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#content-container {
    width: 300%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    font-size: 0px;
    transition: left 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: left 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: left 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: left 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: left 0.5s ease;
}

#content-container > div {
    width: 33.33%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 15px;
}

#content1 {
    background: red;
}

#content2 {
    background: orange;
}

#content3 {
    background: green;
}
```

JS:

```
$("#right1, #left3").on("click", function() {
    // This fires when 'right' is pressed on content 1,
    // or 'left' is pressed on content 3. In both cases
    // we want to move to show content 2.
    $("#content-container").css({left: "-100%"});
});

$("#left2").on("click", function() {
    // This fires when 'left' is pressed on content 2.
    // We want to move to show content 1.
    $("#content-container").css({left: "0%"});
});

$("#right2").on("click", function() {
    // This fires when 'right' is pressed on content 2.
    // We want to move to show content 3.
    $("#content-container").css({left: "-200%"});
});
```

To explain, this sliding effect is based around CSS3 transitions. The `*-transition` properties in the CSS specify that the `left` property should be animated with length 0.5s, using the ease movement. This means that when you change the `left` property of the content-container div, the browser animates the change to create the sliding effect you wanted, rather than just doing it instantly.

The way the pages work is that each content div is set to 1/3 of the width of the content-container div, i.e. `width: 33.33%`. The content-container div is 3 times the width of the page, i.e. `width: 300%`. The content divs inside are made to be side-by-side using `display: inline-block`, and with this method you need to set `font-size: 0px` on the content-container div and re-set `font-size: (xyz)px` in the content divs. This is a quirk of the way `inline-block` works, but by doing the above you remove the horizontal space between the 3 content divs.

Finally, the included JS uses jQuery (but you could do it without) to create event handlers for the links which switch pages. These event handlers are commented so should be self-explanatory, but basically they alter the `left` property of the content-container div according to the page that needs to be displayed.

This JSFiddle shows it working: http://jsfiddle.net/CN8z6/1/

Comment: Seriously i love you! You made my day! Thanks!

Comment: Do you know how to start my document at content2?

Comment: Glad I could be of assistance. And yes - in the CSS of `#content-container` just change `left: 0;` to `left: -100%;`. That moves the content container div which holds all 3 content divs to the left by the size of 1 content div, thereby showing you content 2 by default.